# how to assign values to array

Tags: asp.net

how to assign database value to  arrays. i tried like this...

```
 da = new SqlDataAdapter("select emname from emp", con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "emp");
        if(ds.Tables [0].Rows.Count >0)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<ds.Tables [0].Rows .Count ;i++)
            {
                string[] myArray = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["emname"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

but it is giving error that can't convert string to string[]
please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select emname from emp", con);
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "emp");
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
   string[] myArray = new string[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
   for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       myArray[i] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["emname"].ToString();
   }
   // Use myArray here...
}
```

Note that there are neater ways of doing this using LINQ, but if you're quite new to C#/.NET I'd advise you to become familiar with the basics before diving into LINQ.

Comment: @surya- if you do decide to look at LINQ, you will want to look at LINQ to DataSet- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx

Comment: LINQ in Action (Fabrice Marguerie, Steve Eichert, and Jim Wooley) and Pro LINQ (Joe Rattz) are both good. I've also heard good things about Essential LINQ (Charlie Calvert and Dinesh Kulkarni) but I haven't read it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to innitialize a new array on every loop, and on top of that you are also trying to assign it as a string and not an array.

string[][] myArray = ds.Tables[0].Rows would be the proper solution. Also note that rows is a multidimentional array. You could also use for example string[] myArray = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0] if you want an array populated with a specific row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array of all the names, you can just convert an array of `DataRow` into an array of `string` like that:

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select emname from emp", con);
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "emp");
string[] myArray = Array.ConvertAll<DataRow, string>(ds.Tables[0].Select(), 
                         delegate(DataRow row) { return row["emname"].ToString(); });
```